# Помогите разъединить скрипт пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, html

Вот скрипт

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="20">20</button>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="30">30</button>
<button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="40">40</button>
  <script>
    var result = document.getElementById('result')
    var num = 0;
    function setNumber(e){
      result.innerHTML = num += parseInt(e.value);  
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    #result{
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать div отдельно от кнопок. Например кнопки в низу сайта а число отображается в верху

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result')
var num = 0;
function setNumber(e){
      result.innerHTML = num += parseInt(e.value);  
}
```

```css
#result{
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="20">20</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="30">30</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="40">40</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно на flexbox, обернув кнопки в div и задав высоту флекс контейнеру (в данном случае body).

Кнопки внизу.

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result')
var num = 0;

function setNumber(e) {
  result.innerHTML = num += parseInt(e.value);
}
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="20">20</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="30">30</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="40">40</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Кнопки справа.

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result')
var num = 0;

function setNumber(e) {
  result.innerHTML = num += parseInt(e.value);
}
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="20">20</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="30">30</button>
    <button onClick="setNumber(this)" value="40">40</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Первый обернуть в скрипт а второй в стиль?

Comment: @АннаСандалова В html коде кнопки оберните в `div`. В css код добавьте код для body из моего примера.

Comment: Я сделал так. Но не работает

Comment: В примере же работает. Ищите внимательней различия у вас и в примере или полностью скопируйте код из примера.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста вот это http://prntscr.com/cw635h  в начале и в конце я ставлю style

Comment: А здесь http://prntscr.com/cw63mk script

Comment: Да и еще изменения в html.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста http://prntscr.com/cw6c20     Я так все вставила

Comment: Вставили так, а вот куда вы вставляете не ясно

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cw6fwq   в html  и не работает(((   Спасибо за отзывчивость

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас за сервис или редактор, поэтому не могу помочь с правильной вставкой.